# Developing c# project with linux server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, nant, ubuntu-server

The school has given us an ubuntu server to use for an svn repository, trac, and building automated processes. The people in my group are all using visual stuido to develop the project.

Right now the server is setup to use ant as the builder and auto reports junit and javadocs to the apache webserver for easy viewing on the web.

My question is, how do I setup the server to do the same thing but for a c# project.

What I have done is install mono on the server. Now I am looking into nant to replace ant on the server but I am struggling to come up with a script to run with the post-commit hook.

From my understanding, we will develop in visual studio and commit through svn and then nant will execute when post-commit hook is called by the svn server.

I also found nunit to replace junit for testing purposes.

Sorry for the random thoughts but basically I am looking for advice/suggestions on how the setup the server for the project. am I headed in the right direction?

Comment: have you looked at the `Ubuntu` site there are lots of good examples and it has a really good support group

Comment: Forget post-commit hooks, get Jenkins to do this part for you. It'll make your life much easier. As for running C# on Ubuntu - you need to go to the Mono docs for that.

Answer (score 0):

Run NAnt through mono or run XBuild (similar to MSBuild).  post-commit hooks are ok for very light things, but look at Jenkins or TeamCity or travis-ci.org or AppVeyor or AppHarbor for anything major.  Even better, git publish to Azure Web Apps with a free DreamSpark account, and it'll build and deploy on a post-commit hook.